# I Keep Getting Rake Aborted After Do DB Migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to learn Rails for the first time and I keep getting this error in my console after I try to load the page "post" in my browser.

I hope I am explaining this correctly. Anyone know how to fix this issue?

```
Started GET "/posts" for localhost at 2014-08-14 20:02:51 -0400
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"

ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError (

Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run:

        bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development

):
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:389:in `check_pending!'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Does running `bundle exec rake db:migrate` yield the same?

Comment: Yeah @DaveNewton I did run bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development and I got the same error.

Comment: @CodyCaughlan, I tried your command I got the same error in my console.

Comment: So when you try to run db:migrate it tells you that you need to run db:migrate? That doesn't make sense

Comment: Yeah I know it seems like it doesn't register with the system that I am running the command db:migrate. It's just weird and cannot seem to figure it out...

Comment: What if you delete your `db/schema.rb` before running the migrations? Does your db actually look correct to you?

Comment: @BradWerth, I haven't tried deleting my db/schema.rb. How do you look inside your db? What command do you use in CLI to look?

Comment: I use SQLyog for mysql, sqlite database browser for sqlite, and pgAdmin for postgress... Try deleting it, running migrations will restore it (or if they still fail, you can restore from vcs)...

Comment: @BradWerth I don't mean to be a ditz here, but what's the command to delete db/schema.rb? I tried words delete and remove, but nothing happens.

Comment: No worries. It's just a file on the file system. You should be able to navigate to the app directory and simply delete the file as normal.

Comment: @BradWerth, Am I doing this correctly: root@one:~/tredster# cd app
root@one:~/tredster/app# delete db/schema.rb

Comment: I'm not sure which OS you're using (or where your app is located - app root is just a shorthand for the location that your app is located in), but you probably want `rm` instead of `delete`.

Comment: @BradWerth I am using Ubuntu 12.04LTS via Putty terminal. I tried to delete the db/schema.rb file once I got in the app directory, but it says no file found. I also tried the db directory.

Comment: It sounds like the db was never created, have you tried the suggestions put forth in the answer by @lsaffie?

Comment: @BradWerth Yes I did. I will try again though to see. Other than that maybe I should do a clean uninstall of Rails,Ruby, and Gems. Then start over. However, I don't want to run away from this problem by simply erasing and starting over because I want to fix this issue and gain some confidence.

Comment: It's probably your app, more than your environment, but who knows. Maybe just start with a new app, and see if you can run migrations, there, for starters... Good luck...

Comment: @BradWerth Yeah I tried a new app earlier and got the same migration errors. I think it's my environment. Thanks for all the help, I really appreciate man. :)

Comment: You're welcome. You might enjoy http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure your database exists. Try doing 
bundle exec rake db:create RAILS_ENV=development
bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development

Try adding bundle in case the rake version you're using is in the Gemfile

then restart your server. One more thing you may want to try is to access the console and see if you experience the same behaviour.

bundle exec rails c